# Qt app language translation on ios

Tags: ios, qt

I trying a simple hell world qt quick app on ios & android.
I did the following:
1. Took the most basic hello world qt quick project with "Hello World" written with qsTr() of course
2. Ran lupdate on main.qml & created main_no.ts for norwegian
3. Opened main_no.ts in linguist app. Gave the translation for "Hello World" as "Hei Verden"
4. Saved main_no.ts
5. Ran lrelease on main_no.ts. This created main_no.qm
6. Opened my project's .pro file and added the following
TRANSLATIONS += main_no.ts

7. Rebuilt my app
8. Ran it on iPhone where the language was set to english
9. App launched. The text "Hello World" showed up. All great untill now
10. Next I changed the language to Norwegian ("Norsk Bokmal").
11. Relaunched the app & it crashed !!!!!

After this it keeps crashing on every launch even if I change the language back to English.

Can anyone please tell what is wrong that I am doing ?

Thanks a many in advance.

Comment: I want to achieve the translation for the text "hello world" to Norwegian for qt app on ios. That is my final goal

Comment: Where does it crash? Run it in a debugger.